# Add a delay in image slideshow Jquery

Tags: jquery, image, slideshow

i have a images slideshow using Jquery. I want it change automatically every 5 seconds or custom time. And in my slideshow have next button that used to generate next slideshow.

But here is my problem.

1. If i run first or first time click, it not to change in next picture. But in second, third, .. click it can change continuously.

   2.How to add auto change the pictures, in custom timeout. Because i try to add setTimeout() , and i use Next button make the slideshow change very fast (blinking).

HTML File :

```
<div class="slider">
    Next &raquo;
</div>

<div class="subbox1">
<div class="images">
    <img src="https://imageshack.us/a/img203/2859/thumb73.jpg" />
    <img src="https://imageshack.us/a/img20/4360/thumb72.jpg" />
    <img src="https://imageshack.us/a/img855/3400/thumb61h.jpg" />
</div>
</div>

<div class="subbox1">
<div class="images">
    <img src="https://imageshack.us/a/img853/3924/thumb71.jpg" />
    <img src="https://imageshack.us/a/img845/5805/thumb62m.jpg" />
    <img src="https://imageshack.us/scaled/large/163/thumb2nv.jpg" />
</div>
</div>
```

CSS File

```
.slider {
    padding : 10px;
    background : #000;
    color : #FFF;
    width : 100px;
    margin-left : 10px;
}
.subbox1{
    float : left;
    width : 227px;
    height: 189px;
    position : relative;
    margin : 10px;
}

.images img {
    position : absolute;
    top : 0;
}


JS File
function anim(selector) {
    $(".images img", selector).first().appendTo($('.images', selector)).fadeOut(500);   
    $(".images img", selector).first().fadeIn(500);

    //Make slideshow blink
    setTimeout(function(){anim(selector)}, 5000);
}

$(".slider").click(function() {
    $(".subbox1").each(function() {anim(this)});
});
```

Here is my fiddle [RESULT](http://jsfiddle.net/fanjavaid/5H5Xq/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the `setInterval()` method. Then create a variable `i` as a counter and every 500ms increase the value.

```
var i = 0, max = 5;
var interval = setInterval(function(){
    showSlide(i);
    i = 1 >= max ? 0 : ++i;
}, 500);

next_button.onclick = function(){
    i += 1;
    showSlide(i);
}
```

good lucky

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer. It work now, but i wonder what is max variabel?

Comment: `max` variable is the number os slides. If the the current slide is 5, the next slide must be 0 instead of 6 (because doesn't exist)

Comment: Oh ok i can see it now. But if there are less with my code? Because slideshow will only change the image on third click event. At the first and second click event, image does not switch to the next slide.